# Implementing Identity service as a thin abstraction on Azure AD

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory

We are in the process of fully operationalising Azure, with Azure AD used as the de-facto identity and access management service across all on-prem and cloud services.

For Azure based services  (especially PaaS) there is native support for Azure AD integration and it works well for majority of our identity use cases (System-to-System, User-to-System).

However with services which are on-prem, we are planning to implement a thin layer of abstraction in .net core over Azure AD endpoints to expose as a "enterprise identity service". This enterprise identity service will be a https service. The "enterprise identity service" is to act as a facade over Azure AD endpoints (like oauth2/authorize or oauth2/token) so that the consumers/clients do not know about the underlying Azure AD component.

This helps us future proof our on-prem applications, and decouple them from Azure AD, in case we decide to move to another identity provider.

Is this an approach that is common when it comes to implementing identity using Azure AD? Or is it needless complexity and we should stick to using Azure AD directly.

thanks

Comment: Have you looked at [IdentityServer](https://identityserver.io)? It likely has the decoupling already that you described

Comment: For me, I'm not sure what the advantage of decoupling the on-prem services is. If you are going to modify their code anyway to use OpenID Connect to connect to your custom IdP, you might as well connect them to AAD. The setup would be the same, just different config settings. You do have to make an app registration for each app then though. Also, remember to count the maintenance/management your identity provider is going to require :)

Comment: @timlentine - there is not much appetite within the broader team to use identity server. we looked at it and though it is pretty powerful, the team feels we are not ready for it.

Comment: @juunas - thanks. i see what you mean. within our ecosystem there are plenty of on-prem applications with no internet connectivity. if they are to use Azure AD directly, they would require network to open access to www. with this thin facade hosted internally, these applications would only ever talk to another on-prem application, which will then route calls to internet.

Comment: @nesh_s fair enough, though rolling your own facade may be riskier than implementing something made by experts.